# Strange error when unvboxing in `\hbox`

Tags: errors, boxes, plain-tex

and merry Christmas!

I've encountered a strange error message on TeX level which cost me quite some time to unravel because it was so exceptionally unhelpful...

Here's a minimal plain TeX example:

```
\newbox\tempbox
\hbox{%
  \begingroup
    \setbox\tempbox=\vbox{foo}
    \unvbox\tempbox
  \endgroup
}
\bye
```

and the output:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
<to be read again> 
                   \unvbox 
l.5     \unvbox
               \tempbox
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
<to be read again> 
                   \unvbox 
l.5     \unvbox
               \tempbox
! Extra \endgroup.
l.6   \endgroup
               
! Too many }'s.
l.7 }
```

It does make a twisted sort of sense, like `\unvbox` crying "get me out of here" and inserting group closing commands until it has escaped from the hbox...

But of course in the real world, all this was buried several levels deep in macro constructs and the main problem with debugging was that I absolutely didn't remember I was inside an `\hbox`.

Furthermore, the group-ending commands inserted by the crazy `\unvbox` were totally f*ing up the grouping structure, so that the whole mess ended with an emergency break.

In this MWE, the box is undefined by the inserted `\endgroup`, so `\unvbox` operates on the empty box.

A simple "you can't unvbox in an hbox; ignored" would have been immeasurably more helpful.

Is there a rationale for this behaviour?

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with you. There is no "error message", only a statement of the recovery action. This also applies to "missing $ inserted" errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 286 of the TeXbook we find

> Some commands are incompatible with horizontal mode because they are intrinsically vertical. When the following commands appear in unrestricted horizontal mode, they cause TeX to conclude the current paragraph:
>
> ⟨vertical command⟩ → `\unvbox` | `\unvcopy` | `\halign` | `\hrule` |
>         `\vskip` | `\vfil` | `\vfill` | `\vss` | `\vfilneg` | `\end` | `\dump`
>
> The appearance of a ⟨vertical command⟩ in restricted horizontal mode is forbidden, but in regular horizontal mode it causes TEX to insert the token **par** into the input; after reading and expanding this **par** token, TeX will see the ⟨vertical command⟩ token again. (The current meaning of the control sequence `\par` will be used; **par** might no longer stand for TeX’s `\par` primitive.)

You get exactly the same error with `\hbox{a\vfil}`.

Module 1062 of `tex.web` might help

> Many of the actions related to box-making are triggered by the appearance of braces in the input. For example, when the user says ‘`\hbox to 100pt{⟨hlist⟩}`’ in vertical mode, the information about the box size (100pt, *exactly*) is put onto save stack with a level boundary word just above it, and *cur_group* ← *adjusted_hbox_group*; TeX enters restricted horizontal mode to process the hlist. The right brace eventually causes *save_stack* to be restored to its former state, at which time the information about the box size (100pt, *exactly*) is available once again; a box is packaged and we leave restricted horizontal mode, appending the new box to the current list of the enclosing mode (in this case to the current list of vertical mode), followed by any vertical adjustments that were removed from the box by *hpack*.

<sup>Read **par** as the a boxed `par`.</sup>

There *might* be an error such as “vertical command found in restricted horizontal mode” supplementing the “Missing `}` inserted” (in your case there's also an `\endgroup` to supply first). There is a class of error messages `You can’t use x in y mode` (module 1049), but it would not be very useful here, because inserting the proper tokens to end restricted horizontal mode would be needed anyway and ignoring the `\unvbox` command would need further processing and possibly more errors than what you find here.

Now, since `\unvbox` is only legal in unrestricted horizontal mode, you could fix your code as

```
\relax\ifhmode
  \ifinner
    % possibly issue a warning
    \box
  \else
    \unvbox % will trigger insertion of \par
  \fi
\else
  \unvbox
\fi
```

The warning should point out that the output might not be as intended. No need to `\expandafter` in order to remove `\fi` or `\else`, because after `\box` or `\unvbox` TeX will expand tokens until finding a ⟨number⟩.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I'm accepting your answer as it probably doesn't make sense to discuss any further here – it _was_ indeed to be expected and is also documented, so the issue was really my unfamiliarity with the deeper workings of TeX here.

Comment: But I can't agree that inserting the `\endgroup` and `}` and whatnot before `\unvbox` makes any sense. Those items are coming later at their proper places, so any code in between is invalidated by the group's end.
The only scenario where it would make sense would be if they had indeed be forgotten, which I find unlikely.
Ignoring the `\unvbox` (which just creates some vertical items and doesn't have far reaching structural impact like `\endgroup`) would make much more sense.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I agree with you that this might be solved in a different way (at least with a more transparent error message), but that's how it is. Always remember to do `\ifhmode\ifinner\box\else\unvbox\fi\else\unvbox\fi` maybe adding a warning before `\vbox`.

Comment: Very good advice, thanks. Could you add that to your answer to benefit future users running into the same problem?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Added.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of it comes down to the structure of the TeX program. From §1064 of tex.web:

> We have to deal with errors in which braces and such things are not properly nested. Sometimes the user makes an error of commission by inserting an extra symbol, but sometimes the user makes an error of omission. TeX can’t always tell one from the other, so it makes a guess and tries to avoid getting into a loop.

In this instance what's happening is that TeX's best guess is that there should have been a `}` before the `\unvbox` since the `\unvbox` doesn't belong there. It's worth remembering that TeX is written largely with 1970s technology and the limitations thereof.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a rationale for this behaviour?

As others have said, you could argue that this is due to the age of TeX, but I think the behaviour of force ending the inner hmode an thus allowing the vertical list to be output is quite reasonable even now,  even though it often causes more or less spurious errors when the "real" end of group is encountered.

After any error the PDF should just be seen as a potential debugging aim, sensible PDF output is a non-aim.  The suggested alternative fallback of skipping the unvbox would hide most of the output from the PDF and (perhaps) make it harder to see the location of the problem.

This is consistent with the rest of the error recovery in TeX. If you use `alpha` in tex mode it force starts math mode putting a `$` in front, even though this almost always trashes the rest of the paragraph as it has no good way to stop math mode. It does not drop the `\alpha`.

Comment: I'm not arguing that erroneous output could occur. That of course is to be expected after an error.
But inserting `\endgroup` fundamentally alters the dynamic scoping "block structure" of the program. More likely than not, the box to be unvboxed will get undefined, so `\unvbox` won't output anything anyway.

Comment: @StephanLehmke possibly (although I'd say more likely not, boxing the vbox inside that group would be less likely I'd think) However my main point is that the error recovery even if not very useful is consistent with almost all error recovery steps  taken by TeX it doesn't  usually ignore future tokens,, it almost always inserts tokens at the current point  to get into a legal context, adding `$` to get into math, `\par` to get into vmode or as here `\endgroup` then `}` to get out of hmode, the behaviour is  consistently "add something here now, worry about what comes later when it comes...."

Comment: Ok, we can agree that it's consistent :-)

Comment: Like throwing my purse down the drain is consistent with losing my watch there beforehand...

Comment: @StephanLehmke excellent plan, they will then both wash up together on some distant shore.

Comment: btw, I edited the code in the question to make the point about emptying the box.

Comment: @StephanLehmke sneaky:-)